# CMAKE and MKOCTFILE

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm working on a C/C++ project and I'm using CMAKE 3.5.2 for build. However, now I must to include a C++ file which uses Octave functions. I am able to compile this source file directly by line command using this command: `mkoctfile --link-stand-alone new_oct_file -o final_library`.

I'm struggling to do CMAKE execute this command. I've tried to use an `add_custom_command`, but it didn't work. Can someome help me?

My CMAKE has the following structure

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(final_library)

add_executable(final_library  program.c 
./Commons/util.c 
./Tools/xulambs_tool.cpp)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(/usr/include/octave-4.0.0/octave)

install(TARGETS final-library RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)

add_subdirectory(Commons)
add_subdirectory(Tools)
```

I've tried to add the following command (it does not work):

```
set(MKOCTFILE "mkoctfile")
set(OCTARG "--link-stand-alone")
add_custom_command(TARGET reordering-library 
       PRE_LINK 
       COMMAND ${MKOCTFILE} ARGS ${OCTARG} ./Tools/tool_octave.cpp)
```

The compilation output is

```
[  4%] Linking CXX executable final-library
g++: error: ./Tools/tool_octave.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/final-library.dir/build.make:694: recipe for target 'final-library' failed
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/final-library.dir/all' failed
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [final-library] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/final-library.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thanks.

Comment: This: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_sf/GENERATED.html should help

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you and I fixed it by adding the liboctinterp.so in the target_link_libraries of the CMakeLists.txt file.

My current cmake file contains the following:

add_executable(MyEXE main.cc)
target_link_libraries(MyEXE liboctave.so liboctinterp.so)

Answer (score 1):

The command at pre link is probably not executed in the source directory, so the relative path you used in the script will be invalid. Try using an absolute path, something like:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET reordering-library 
   PRE_LINK 
   COMMAND ${MKOCTFILE} ARGS ${OCTARG}
   "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Tools/tool_octave.cpp"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I've tried your suggestion. Anything has changed.

Comment: @tnas This solution is basically correct, you have to find out in which way the path is wrong. Try printing the path with `message(STATUS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Tools/tool_octave.cpp")`

Comment: The suggestion of @wasthishelpul is ok. But, my custom command doesn't run. I've edited it as `set(OCTAVETOOL "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Tools/tool_octave.cpp")
add_custom_command(OUTPUT tool_octave.out COMMAND mkoctfile --link-stand-alone ${OCTAVETOOL} COMMENT "-- Compiling Octave Tool algorithm.")`. The console has not displayed my comment. Why?

Comment: And I must to link tool_octave.out with the final_library and thereby to generate one executable file. I've tried `add_dependencies(final-library tool_octave.out)` without success.

Comment: @tnas: The answer suggests to use command flow `add_custom_command(TARGET)`, but you use `add_custom_command(OUTPUT)` which is differ: it requires some target (created with `add_custom_target`) to be dependend from file `tool_octave.out`, otherwise adding a command has no effect. As for linking, it is performed with command [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html).